# How to get rows WHERE column is less than variable?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to collect the data that smaller than '80000' for example

```
SELECT * FROM `apartments` WHERE `building_num`='1' AND `price` < '800000' ORDER by `apartment_num` ASC
```

in the response printing prices:

> 1249661,790537,1266228,1267359,1177575

Its showing results that bigger than 800,000 and I did less.

Any one have an idea?

Comment: You have one too many 0s in your query, 800000 vs 80000, also, price doesn't want to be quoted, so < 80000 ORDER .

Comment: What type does price column have?

Comment: @MaximFedorov I forgot it was varchar I changed it to INT and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Why are you comparing strings?

```
 SELECT * FROM `apartments`
 WHERE `building_num`='1' AND `price` < 800000 
 ORDER by `apartment_num` ASC
```

Unless it’s a char column, and then that’s another issue.

The reason you’re getting this result, is that by the ASCII enconding(which is used when comparing string) , “11” is less then “2” because of the first character .